# Pass multiple optional parameters to a C# function

Tags: c#, function, parameters

Is there a way to set up a C# function to accept any number of parameters? For example, could you set up a function such that the following all work -

```
x = AddUp(2, 3)

x = AddUp(5, 7, 8, 2)

x = AddUp(43, 545, 23, 656, 23, 64, 234, 44)
```

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Use a *parameter array* with the `params` modifier:

```
public static int AddUp(params int[] values)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you want to make sure there's at least *one* value (rather than a possibly empty array) then specify that separately:

```
public static int AddUp(int firstValue, params int[] values)
```

(Set `sum` to `firstValue` to start with in the implementation.)

Note that you should also check the array reference for nullity in the normal way. Within the method, the parameter is a perfectly ordinary array. The parameter array modifier only makes a difference when you *call* the method. Basically the compiler turns:

```
int x = AddUp(4, 5, 6);
```

into something like:

```
int[] tmp = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
int x = AddUp(tmp);
```

You *can* call it with a perfectly normal array though - so the latter syntax is valid in source code as well.

Comment: In `public static int AddUp(params int[] values)` the `values` will always be of type `T[]`? Can it not be of type `params IEnumerable<T> values` or `params List<T> values`. I tried using `params IEnumerable<T> values` but it gave me error, which was later resolved using `params IEnumerable<T>[] values`. Why so?

Comment: @barnes: `params` only works for array types (at the moment; there have been proposals to allow other types). You almost certainly *don't* want `params IEnumerable<T>[]` as that would be an array of sequences.

Answer (score 7):

C# 4.0 also supports optional parameters, which could be useful in some other situations. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026022658/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/02/05/c-4.0-optional-parameters.aspx) article.

Answer (score 5):

1.You can make overload functions.

```
SomeF(strin s){}   
SomeF(string s, string s2){}    
SomeF(string s1, string s2, string s3){}
```

More info: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

2.or you may create one function with params

```
SomeF( params string[] paramArray){}
SomeF("aa","bb", "cc", "dd", "ff"); // pass as many as you like
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

3.or you can use simple array

```
Main(string[] args){}
```

Comment: Overloading in example 1 presented here is unnecessary, since that function can be written as :
SomeF(string s, string s2 = "", string s3 = ""){ }