# In C#, is it possible to call a method (which has default parameters) with "as many parameters as I have"?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

That is, I have a method such as the following:

```
public static int CreateTaskGroup(string TaskGroupName, 
    string Market = "en-us", string Project = "MyProject", 
    string Team = "DefaultTeam", string SatelliteID="abc");
```

I would like to call this method from the command line, by reading the standard array of command line arguments. The obvious way to do it would be as follows:

```
 if (args.Length == 1) CreateTaskGroup(args[0]);
 if (args.Length == 2) CreateTaskGroup(args[0], args[1]);
 if (args.Length == 3) CreateTaskGroup(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
```

Is it possible to do this in a more concise way?

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996426/pass-multiple-optional-parameters-to-a-c-sharp-function

Comment: are the parameters always in the same order?

Comment: @Wug, I do not believe that question is similar enough to be helpful to the OP.  (unless the OP wants to make his method a lot less readable)

Comment: He already has an array of arguments.  He will still have to add handling for the default values though.  All it really does is move the yuckiness from the calling to the definition.  Since its defined once and called multiple times, it might be an OK trade off.

Comment: @ptay89, yes, the parameters will always be passed in the same order.

Comment: @Wug, to clarify, when I say "concise", I do want to preserve readability. I think that if I have to add the logic to deal with default arguments into the method definition, the overall amount of code would actually be more.

Comment: There are several available solutions, you can look between them and see how they handle it.  It is a trade-off though, the work still has to happen, just in different places.

Comment: @Wug, he "already has an array of arguments" -- he has that array because that's all he gets from a `Main` method.  That's not a very good reason to go ruining the method signatures further down the line by exchanging nice clear parameter names with a string array.  (he only has to deal with the `Main` method one time in one place, so I don't see how your logic holds)

Comment: If he finds himself so inclined, he can call it with `CreateTaskGroup(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);` too.  That is one of the reasons I recommend the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one alternative, with the downside that you have to redeclare the default value constants:

```
CreateTaskGroup(
    args[0],
    args.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? "en-us",
    args.ElementAtOrDefault(2) ?? "MyProject",
    args.ElementAtOrDefault(3) ?? "DefaultTeam",
    args.ElementAtOrDefault(4) ?? "abc");
```

You can reduce this issue by declaring the strings as `const`s, e.g.:

```
public const string MarketDefault = "en-us";
public static int CreateTaskGroup(string TaskGroupName,
    string Market = MarketDefault, ...)

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateTaskGroup(
        args[0],
        args.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? MarketDefault,
        ...);
}
```

But then it's not guaranteed by the compiler, nor overtly obvious, that `MarketDefault` is, in fact, still (code can be refactored in the future) the default for `Market`.

Edit: Here's an alternate solution, using reflection:

```
var argsForMethod = new List<string>(args);
var m = typeof(Program).GetMethod("CreateTaskGroup");
foreach (var p in m.GetParameters().Skip(args.Length))
    if (p.Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.HasDefault))
        argsForMethod.Add((string)p.DefaultValue);
    else
        throw new NotImplementedException();
var result = (int)m.Invoke(null, argsForMethod.ToArray());
```

This can be a bit hard to read, and won't be too fast, but it does what you asked, without resorting to repetitive code, or having any uncertainty as to the default value of the parameters.  You'll probably want to add some error handling for too few or too many parameters.  I prefer this solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about using params in CreateTaskGroup something like this

```
 public static int CreateTaskGroup(params string[] args) 
 {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < args.Length ; i++ )
    {
      ............
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would implement the class to keep things clean and to assign the responsibility of knowing the default values to the TaskGroupCreator.

```
public class TaskGroupCreator
{
    private string[] values;

    public TaskGroupCreator(string[] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public string TaskGroupName
    {
        get { return values[0]; }
    }

    public string Market
    {
        get { return this.GetElement(1, "en-us"); }
    }

    public string Project 
    {
        get { return this.GetElement(2, "MyProject"); }
    }

    public string Team 
    {
        get { return this.GetElement(3, "DefaultTeam"); }
    }

    public string SatelliteID 
    {
        get { return this.GetElement(4, "abc"); }
    }

    public int CreateTaskGroup()
    {
        // Do stuff with your properties...
    }

    private string GetElement(int index, string defaultValue)
    {
        return this.values.ElementAtOrDefault(index) ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var taskGroup = new TaskGroupCreator(args).CreateTaskGroup();
```

Comment: Ha! That's interesting.  I have never programmed in Java... The pattern must have transferred to the .NET community then.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best out of what I've come up with:

```
public static int CreateTaskGroup(string[] arguments)
{
    // optional error handling here

    string TaskGroupName = arguments[0];
    string Market        = arguments.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? "en-us";
    string Project       = arguments.ElementAtOrDefault(2) ?? "MyProject";
    string Team          = arguments.ElementAtOrDefault(3) ?? "DefaultTeam";
    string SatelliteID   = arguments.ElementAtOrDefault(4) ?? "abc";

    // function body as it was
```

This does the same thing but is less concise:

```
public static int CreateTaskGroup(string[] arguments)
{
    string TaskGroupName, Market, Project, Team, SatelliteID;
    switch (arguments.Length)
    {
    case 5:
        string SatelliteID   = arguments[4] ?? "abc";
        goto case 4;
    case 4:
        string Team          = arguments[3] ?? "DefaultTeam";
        goto case 3;
    case 3:
        string Project       = arguments[2] ?? "MyProject";
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
        string Market        = arguments[1] ?? "en-us";
        goto case 1;
    case 1:
        string TaskGroupName = arguments[0];
        break;
    case 0:
        // error handling here;
    }

    // function body as it was
```

You could call it concisely like this:

```
CreateTaskGroup(args);
```

Comment: `arguments[4]` isn't going to be null, it's going to throw an out of bounds exception

Comment: I realized that after I posted it.  the switch statement fixed it, but made it ugly at the same time. :(

Comment: But now all the variables are scoped to the switch statement only. You can't use them in the rest of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way..

```
CreateTaskGroup(args);

//.....

public static int CreateTaskGroup(params string[] args) {
    if (args.Length == 0) throw new Exception("nope!");
    args = args.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 5 - args.Length)
        .Select<int, string>(_ => null)).ToArray();
    string TaskGroupName = args[0];
    string Market = args[1] ?? "en-us";
    string Project = args[2] ?? "MyProject";
    string Team = args[3] ?? "DefaultTeam";
    string SatelliteID = args[4] ?? "abc";
    //......
}
```

`params` keyword isn't mandatory, but could be convenient...