# Pass multiple numbers into an Add method that uses a params modifier?

Tags: c#

Refer to this answer: [Pass multiple optional parameters to a C# function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996426/pass-multiple-optional-parameters-to-a-c-sharp-function)
Question about Params (to a point).  What I want to know is, how (if possible) can this be used to take user input rather than predefined numbers?
So, I understand that I can do Console.Write(calculator.Add(1, 43, 23)) but would like to deal with user input.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(calculator.Add(input));
    }
}

public class Calculator
{
    public int Add(params int[] numbers)
    {
        var sum = 0;
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work. I might have made syntax errors :D

```c#
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        var input = GetNumbers();
        calculator.Add(input);
        Console.WriteLine(calculator.Add(input));
    }

    public static int[] GetNumbers()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Numbers Seperated With a Space");
      string input = Console.ReadLine(); //Get user input with this
      string[] arr = input.Split(' '); //Split the input at spaces
      int[] output = new int[arr.Length]; //create in array of same length

      for(int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
      {
          output[i] = Int32.Parse(arr[i]); //parse every value and add to int array
      }
      return output;
    }
}

public class Calculator
{
    public int Add(params int[] numbers)
    {
        var sum = 0;
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this.  Any idea why my question has been downvoted?  I don't understand, its a legitimate question.  This site does dismay me sometimes.  What is its point if not for people like me to come and learn from it, and gain others knowledge.

Comment: Just to say that in this as well as the OP, there's an unnecessary line of `calculator.Add(input);` before the `Console.WriteLine(calculator.Add(input));`. OP may be interested in putting in a variable where the result is to be re-used.

Comment: Macro, yes I should have edited the code a little before posting.  I left that line in as was because I was in the middle of changes.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the user inputs in an array and pass the array to `Add`.

```
var calculator = new Calculator();
var input = Array.ConvertAll<int>(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '));
calculator.Add(input);
```

Comment: `ConvertAll` needs 2 parameters

Comment: Wish I knew what type of variable `input` was.