# C# specify only second optional argument and use the default value for first

Tags: c#, syntax, optional-arguments

I have a function defined like this:

```
public void Foo(string arg1="defaultvalueForArg1", string arg2="defaultvalueForArg2")
{
    ...
}
```

Now i want to call this function and provide a special value for `arg2`:

```
Foo("defaultvalueForArg1", "specialValueForArg2");
```

This works. But i must copy and paste and explicitly specify the value for `arg1` and i think this is not very clean. For example if the default-value for `arg1` changes I must search for every place where i probably want to update the value for `arg1` to use the new default-value. Is there a syntax or option to use simply the default-value provided for `arg1` specified in `Foo`? Something like `Foo(_, "specialValueForArg2");` (using `_` which you probably known as [discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)).
I can probably overload `Foo` but my question is if there is a real "buildin-function" for this issue in C#.

Comment: `Foo(arg2: "specialValueForArg2");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass multiple optional parameters to a C# function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996426/pass-multiple-optional-parameters-to-a-c-sharp-function)  (specifically, look at the 2nd answer that links to an article about optional params)

Comment: Have you considered named parameters here?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes this is exactly what i need, thank you very much.